# Xubuntu Thunar "Open Terminal Here" opens konsole in homefolder

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, thunar, konsole

When I try to open console/terminal in any folder by drop-down menu in the Thunar, the konsole is opened in /home/user folder.

How to configure "Open Terminal Here" shortcut to open new terminal window correctly?

UPD:

1. Opening the /home/user/Downloads folder
2. There is folder named "FOLDER"
3. Right mouse click on folder "FOLDER"
4. From drop-down menu choosing the "Open Terminal Here" option
5. New terminal (konsole) is running in  the /home/user/ , but should be in /home/user/Downloads

Comment: Xubuntu does not use Konsole, it uses xfce4-terminal. Try with it.

Comment: @GTRONICK Yes, using the xfce4-terminal it is working fine, but I want to use konsole as default.

Comment: If this is what you want make your question clearer.

Comment: @JuanAntonio I have a little update about what I am doing and what I am getting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found solution!!!
In Thunar Edit>Configure custom actions...
then edit "Open Terminal Here"

and replace:

```
exo-open --working-directory %f --launch TerminalEmulator
```

with this:

```
konsole --workdir %f
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, Thunar uses [the `exo-open` command](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/exo/exo-open.1.en), which is [configured in the XFCE settings](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/exo/preferred-applications). If you do not have the XFCE settings app installed, you can instead configure it in `~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc`:

```
TerminalEmulator=konsole
TerminalEmulatorDismissed=true
```

or, another example,

```
TerminalEmulator=kitty
TerminalEmulatorDismissed=true
```

Answer (score 1):

This works when you've selected nothing, folders with blank space, a file, a selection of files, etc.

`{ [ -d %f ] && exo-open --working-directory %f --launch TerminalEmulator ; } || { exo-open --working-directory %d --launch TerminalEmulator ; }`

Available command parameters in thunar Custom Actions:

```
List of valid command parameter variables
Variable    Usage
%f  The path of the first selected file.
%F  The paths to all selected files.
%u  The URI of the first selected file (using the file:-URI scheme).
%U  The URIs of all selected files (using the file:-URI scheme).
%d  The directory of the first selected file.
%D  The directories to all selected files.
%n  The name of the first selected file (without the path).
%N  The names of all selected files (without the paths).
```

The above is equivalent to:

```bsh
if [[ -d %f ]]; then

    exo-open --working-directory %f --launch TerminalEmulator
else

    exo-open --working-directory %d --launch TerminalEmulator
fi
```

Or in pseudo-code:

```
# if the path of the first selected file or directory is a directory
    # open a terminal in the directory of the first file selected
    # or open a terminal in the directory selected
```

Answer (score 1):

First run

```
gedit ~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc
```

Now add the following 2 lines to create an alias of *your favorite Terminal* to be **TerminalEmulator**. Let's say your terminal is *gnome-terminal*

```
TerminalEmulator=gnome-terminal
TerminalEmulatorDismissed=true
```

Save all changes and exit the file editor.
Now go to Thunar: ***Edit>Configure Costum Actions...*** and edit the 2 **Open terminal Here** actions:

1. First Action

   *exo-open --working-directory %f --launch TerminalEmulator*
2. Second Terminal action

   *exo-open --working-directory %d --launch TerminalEmulator*

Now you can test and enjoy.